# how to call the useContext function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

im using the useContext from react ,
i have add boolean state to context but when i use it in the component it's give me typeErro : the setState is not a function

what im doing wrong this is my code ?

```
// context file

import { createContext, useContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

interface TasksContextType {
  isSubmitLoading: boolean;
  setIsSubmitLoading: Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

export const TasksContext = createContext({} as TasksContextType);

export const useTasksContext = () => {
  const context = useContext<TasksContextType>(TasksContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useTasksContext should be used within a TasksContext');
  }
  return context;
};
```

the provider file

```
//provider file 

import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';

import { TasksContext } from './TasksContext';

export const TasksProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {

  const [isSubmitLoading, setIsSubmitLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <TasksContext.Provider
      value={{
        isSubmitLoading,
        setIsSubmitLoading,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </TasksContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

the component where i use the useContext

```
//component 

const { setIsSubmitLoading, isSubmitLoading } = useTasksContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsSubmitLoading(mutation.isLoading);
  }, [mutation, setIsSubmitLoading]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example based on the code you provided so you can see that it works and how to use it (more explanation below):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=73&ssc=63&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMAiB5AsnAMyghDgHIpUMBaAExLIG4BYAKFEljgG8245aSAigCuAG3goAzoiowANHzhpKKGEgDCEAHbqAHgqUipmnfsOt+xpAFECBJBkWW41gMow1SZ-xgBPMCQ4TGApMDU0AAsfOH9A2XQYGzEkECRdGLig5ESAOQhBTICgtyQYDy8AQQxgHWcAX0JiUgo5JjY2LLgAFWkAayktXSQDbuK4AF4eJVC3EQAjEGAYABkIFFpgbQBzAC44eYgIFJRtFhcTGABJKTnF5bWNrb3g0PCYKIAeUvLPdWqYLVtJ9DsdUNoAHwQ871c5sNA6KTwXpSAZDcyTZSqdTokYwAAUIm0ggIWyQtDg0lc2j62ggAHdtJSZCi0WY8WNAgBKOGsAhEmo6VwmVmDdkGOD4rn7UW40bjXguSgwERQJnWOUwT6y8UwTlICH4nXDAw8tj1Dp8gWAoWigAKxAAbsBBFBJdwosAxLRKNp6vtuMpIl6fekAPz7HIYfKCOD1aUJDDJVLpeCK-gI7RIuAAbVmCyWq3Wmx28jglxud0LjxL2wAupj3H8kPjhGITGalWVVUz8Up+Nr+mKTTAAHQOiDO139-hwR0oMQiJATbjp2fr-P3ItPUsz9cV24Fh7F54xdf1C0ufgQj3B72++qfAD0xvM46dLqQUAhSk7l7Y-LaIKTKVGAYCSgmUZJCkaS6NMLiZtm3CbtWJ6luWZSVke261o0UzWK+eJSryVgmHYDgYPiUqTBC8H7mU3SgEgEAiAS1ETLRB5VseO7bPiMBQEuXJlgAjAArAADBJnb8PUZY5lx2E1s8dadkoiHwJEpy0CkGhiMAaB9Ji7GcZhh5bspOz4qCYg0XAACENlqV2KpqpKM6fJsjrlv4KQrtwBBmAAYigSxiH4+xkFIpxSNQJhQMABBkBeP6sHucCfJEIkQgAqlIzyxJEQSanAlR2lcz5Zal6WecAjqpeu66fGAlANY1TUIoIbXteu3AAFJuNguSjkiCU7Ilfj4sh5mobxclwNo4hiGWABMXKXj1s7Pp1BrpQOT4tbtV5bU+XnVcdA7zKxMBCjoekGX0K5acSun6YZ9QQt0EDbNsKQ+V4z5XTAN2QpaTWnXVbV-pagHAaVYEIEc8BSpGcjJrBaZKMqPbucdg6olIE5Tl+3VbaB4FPqTz72h+rpQzClpQTguCjr6rr4p85OIxA8CU2W9BoCIGOjtsZTo6mABCfhXLQ+IUEjZBcp2QA)

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.17.6/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import {
//   default as React,
//   createContext,
//   useContext,
//   useEffect,
//   useState,
//   type Dispatch,
//   type ReactElement,
//   type ReactNode,
//   type SetStateAction,
// } from 'react';

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules instead of the above import statments
const {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useState,
} = React;

type TasksContextType = {
  isSubmitLoading: boolean;
  setIsSubmitLoading: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};

const TasksContext = createContext(undefined as unknown as TasksContextType);

function useTasksContext (): TasksContextType {
  return useContext<TasksContextType>(TasksContext);
}

function TasksProvider ({children}: { children?: ReactNode }): ReactElement {
  const [isSubmitLoading, setIsSubmitLoading] = useState(false);
  return (
    <TasksContext.Provider
      value={{
        isSubmitLoading,
        setIsSubmitLoading,
      }}
    >{children}</TasksContext.Provider>
  );
}

function App (): ReactElement {
  const {isSubmitLoading, setIsSubmitLoading} = useTasksContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setIsSubmitLoading(true), 1500);
  }, [setIsSubmitLoading]);

  const handleClick = () => setIsSubmitLoading(bool => !bool);

  return (
    <div style={{fontFamily: 'sans-serif'}}>

      <h1>Using the Context API</h1>

      <div>
        <pre>
          <code>
            {JSON.stringify({isSubmitLoading}, null, 2)}
          </code>
        </pre>
      </div>

      <button onClick={handleClick}>Toggle state</button>

    </div>
  );
}

function AppRoot (): ReactElement {
  return (
    <TasksProvider>
      <App />
    </TasksProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppRoot />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

You didn't show in your code where you actually use the ContextProvider and the JSX structure of your app, but it's important that you only use `useTasksContext` in components that are rendering inside the Provider root. In the example above, I created a component dedicated to rendering the Provider so that it's out of the way and in the main `App` component, you can just focus on the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if you are within your context provider by checking for a falsy value, but since you initialize context with a value (`{}`) it never will be undefined:

```
import { createContext, useContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

interface TasksContextType {
  isSubmitLoading: boolean;
  setIsSubmitLoading: Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

export const TasksContext = createContext({} as TasksContextType); // Here is your problem, change this to:
// createContext<TasksContextType | undefined>();

export const useTasksContext = () => {
  const context = useContext<TasksContextType>(TasksContext); // You can remove the generic here, it will be inferred 

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useTasksContext should be used within a TasksContext');
  }
  return context;
};
```

Now if you try to use the context somewhere you can't, it will throw an error `useTasksContext should be used within a TasksContext`
Or, if you use it within your context it should work ok.

Also note: You should be memoizing your value prop in TasksContext.Provider, otherwise it will be a new object every time and cause all consumers to rerender.

```
const value = useMemo(() => ({
        isSubmitLoading,
        setIsSubmitLoading,
      }, [isSubmitLoading]) // you can skip setIsSubmitLoading as it is referentially stable
```